# OpenDkim - Eerror loading Key while opendkim-testkey outputs key OK?

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot, opendkim

The `mail.err` has this (I've used `FQDN.example.com` as a marker for my domain):

```
Mar 24 19:08:31 FQDN opendkim[17649]: can't load key from /etc/opendkim/keys/FQDN.example.com/mail.private: Permission denied
Mar 24 19:08:31 FQDN opendkim[17649]: D1EBB1204E1: error loading key 'mail._domainkey.FQDN.example.com'
```

But when I run `opendkim-testkey -d FQDN.example.com -s mail -vvvvv` I get

```
opendkim-testkey: using default configfile /etc/opendkim.conf
opendkim-testkey: checking key 'mail._domainkey.FQDN.example.com'
opendkim-testkey: key not secure
opendkim-testkey: key OK
```

The reason the key is not secure because I set it to `chmod 777` when I thought that the denied permissions had something to do with the file permissions. What is going on here?

Using Debian 10.

Answer (score 1):

In my case helped this

```
chown -R opendkim:opendkim /etc/opendkim
chmod 0750 /etc/opendkim/keys
chmod 0600 /etc/opendkim/keys/default.private
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a permission issue, try tighter settings.

```
chmod 0600
```

Comment: This `chmod` command is missing some pieces...

Answer (score 0):

You've got two issues, one brought about by an incorrect attempt at a fix for the other

```
Mar 24 19:08:31 FQDN opendkim[17649]: can't load key from /etc/opendkim/keys/FQDN.example.com/mail.private: Permission denied
```

This error is telling you that the account running `opendkim` cannot read the file `mail.private` (or one of the intermediate directories).

```
opendkim-testkey: key not secure
```

This is telling you that the permissions on this file (or one of the intermediate directories) are too lax.

You need to ensure that the account running `opendkim` can access the private key, but that no other group or process can do so. Unfortunately I don't run OpenDKIM so I cannot tell you what the correct value should be, but remember permissions are user-group-other, so `chmod 0600 mail.private` might be acceptable and sufficient if the user running `opendkim` owned the file.

Also see [OpenDKIM errors](https://serverfault.com/q/679271/267016) over on ServerFault.

Comment: This is incorrect: ‘key not secure’ indicates only that the public key was fetched without *DNSSEC*. If DNSSEC can be used, the output will be ‘key secure’. But this is unrelated from local private key permissions.

Comment: @glts Can you provide the source for your statement?

Comment: @71GA I don’t think this is well documented … but see the source code of [`opendkim-testkey`](https://github.com/trusteddomainproject/OpenDKIM/blob/2.11.0-Beta2/opendkim/opendkim-testkey.c#L731-L756).